# Is there a program that can output the X & Y co-ordinates of the perimeter of black pixels?

Tags: vb.net, image, edge-detection

I am making a VB maze game and I want the player cursor to unable to move over the black lines in the maze. However I am struggling to use a picture box with transparency.

I tried to program my code so when the boundary of the player picture box intersected with the (black) pixels of the maze picture box it would stop moving. 
However I am unable to find that function in VB.

Is it better to create a list of the co-ordinates of the perimeter of the black lines so when cursor.location = one of specified co-ordinates it would "bounce off"?

My question is there a program that can easily analyse my simple black and white maze image and output all of the co-ordinates of the perimeter of black pixels?

Maze: https://ibb.co/rwN9S4f

Comment: Your question is off topic I'm afraid. This site is for questions about specific code issues rather than how code should be written. Questions that result in opinion based answers aren't allowed. However I would suggest the following. If the image content is outside your control, you might be better creating a boolean 2d array that is the size if the image and iterating over the image to find each black pixel. set each equivalent array element to `True`. When the player moves, check if the move would cause the player to intersect with any elements. If there's an intersection, disallow the move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approach you should consider, depending on how you construct your maze.

**If you want to use an image**, you will need to do some image processing. Without further explanations, I can already tell you that you will want to use a library to do this. This might, though, not suits your needs, as this might be a school work or something.

As to "how to use an image processing library", this is a question in itself. When you decide on one, you should read the tutorials.

**If you don't want to use a special library**, your can draw your own labyrinth. There are labyrinth building algorithms online. [THIS PAGE](http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm) would be a good place to start, for example. The principle is often the same: you divide your space into grids and divide these grids into white blocks with walls.

Have fun!

EDITS:

(1)

Here's a fun way to convert an image into an array of bytes:

```
Dim converter As New ImageConverter
nRow.Signature = converter.ConvertTo(imgSignature, GetType(Byte())
```

Comment: thinking about it could I do 2 for next loop for width and height and identifying the color, and build the data list from that? If black add it to the list of coordinates that’s blocked for the player picture box?

Comment: Yes you can, but you would have to transform your image into an array of pixels - which mean you might end up working with very counter-intuitive values. For an example, if your image is encoded in RGB, there will probably be 3 bytes allowed for every pixel (every byte being 0-255). I used to work like this in c++ with a depth and color camera so my every pixel was even more complicated. Only attempt this if you are experienced enough to tackle it, though, because it'll make your job much harder otherwise.

Comment: And by "array of pixels" I really mean "array of bytes", sadly. So you'll end up one step higher than analyzing the binary code.

Comment: See my edit (1) for an easy way to get an array of bytes from your image!